# Binance Stream Aggregate Trade Streams : Bid or Ask?

Tags: trading, binance, binance-api-client

I'm connected to the stream **Aggregate Trade Streams** from the Binance API, and I can't find from the event returned if it's a bid or a ask. And even from the documentation I don't see how I can distinguish https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/web-socket-streams.md#aggregate-trade-streams
I don't see the point of this stream if I can't distinguish the bid/ask.

An example of event I'm getting:

```
EventTime:1637704801311 
Symbol:DOGEBTC 
TradeID:0 
Price:3.92e-06 
Quantity:326 
BuyerOrderID:0 
SellerOrderID:26377001 
TradeTime:1637704801311 
IsMarketMaker:false 
Ignore:true
```

Comment: This is a trade event, which hasn't bid/ask field. Do you need to subscribe your own orders' stream?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it, the flag `IsMarketMaker` determines if it's a BUY or SELL

Comment: I don't think that's the case.

Comment: Its definitely not the case. Tried this assumption on the data and bid was > ask multiple times